# After Jenkins Version upgrade to 2.426 jenkins service is not starting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, versionupgrade

My Jenkins is currently at 2.176 version, i would like to to version upgrade to 2.426.2 but when i followed the version steps from below the>> https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ and after these steps i could see version is upgraded to latest but jenkins service is not starting and its giving error:

```
 jenkins[2229974]: Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
 jenkins[2229974]:         at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:264)
 jenkins[2229974]: 2024-01-23 03:20:02.420+0000 [id=25]        INFO        hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle#onStatusUpdate: Stoppi>
 jenkins[2229974]: 2024-01-23 03:20:02.447+0000 [id=37]        WARNING        hudson.model.ComputerSet#<clinit>: Failed to i>
 jenkins[2229974]: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
 jenkins[2229974]:         at java.base/java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.>
 jenkins[2229974]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.endBlocking(FileChannelImpl.java:171)
```

I have the latest java 17.

can someone please help me

i need the resolution steps inorder to start the service.